# Заковырка: А или О

Tags: орфография, падежи, вопрос

Подскажите пожалуйста! Как правильно написать:

> В настоящее время он сотрудничествА не осуществляет.

или

> В настоящее время он сотрудничествО не осуществляет.

Спасибо!

Comment: А нельзя ли примерно так: "В настоящее время он с нами не сотрудничает"?

Comment: К сожалению, нет, именно так надо выразиться

Comment: *Закавыку* знал, *заковырку* впервые встречаю!

Comment: Вечер добрый, Артём! Слово, конечно же, есть: ЗАКОВЫ́РКА, -и, род. мн. -рок, дат. -ркам, ж. Прост. То же, что закавычка (во 2 и 3 знач.). (https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0) _Рассказать о знакомстве с Валентином и его угрозах сообщить милиции свои подозрения, если не получит денег. ― Да, неожиданная заковырка, ― задумчиво произнес Комар._ [Лев Дворецкий. Шакалы (2000)] Другое дело — подходит ли оно к этому вопросу?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Римма! Да нашёл я уже, когда писал.) Но "заковырка" встречается в Нацкорпусе 4 раза против 101 "закавыки". ;)

Answer (score 1):

Хитрый у вас вопрос, многосторонний. Будем рассматривать его с помощью рекомендаций Розенталя.

**А.** **Родительный падеж,** имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции *значение подчеркнутого отрицания*, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
5) при выражении дополнения отвлеченными существительными: *не дает оснований, не обнаруживает понимания, не теряет надежды, не скрывает радости, **не осуществляет контроля,** не упускает случая, не делает уступок.*

**(1)** *В настоящее время он **не осуществляет сотрудничества.***

Из НКРЯ:
Из всего состава суда только один судья, постоянно выполняющий административные функции, **не осуществляет** судейской **деятельности.** [Федеральный патентный суд Германии (2003) // «Арбитражный и гражданский процессы», 2004.01.26]
ЦК **не осуществляет** оперативного **руководства** первичными организациями... [Илья Земцов. Апофеоз. Отрывки из книги «Черненко: Советский Союз в канун перестройки» // «Огонек». № 3-5, 1991]

**Б.** **Винительный падеж**, ослабляющий значение отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
3) нередко при инверсии дополнения (постановке его впереди глагола-сказуемого), например: *Журнал я этот не люблю* (Тургенев); *Кулаком правду не убьешь* (Горький); *Трактор им не дали* (Шолохов).

**(2)** *В настоящее время он **сотрудничество не осуществляет.***

**В. 3. Факультативное** употребление родительного и винительного падежа при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со стилистическим различием: **конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи**, конструкции с винительным падежом – для речи разговорной.

Ваше предложение никак нельзя отнести к разговорному формату, а в деловой речи инверсия обычно не используется — текст должен быть понятным, четким, с [прямым порядком слов](https://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?mode=cht&chtid=657&subid=121) (дополнение в этом случае следует за глаголом).
Я бы выбрала первое предложение — с родительным падежом.
Если же необходимо предложение с указанным порядком слов, то винительный падеж в нем вполне уместен (думаю, что ошибки не будет).

[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

Comment: Римма, Большое спасибо за подробный ответ!